# How can I find the remainder of the division??

Tags: abstract-algebra

How can I find the remainder of the division of $173562014.8976$ and $3$ or $9$??
$$$$
If we had $A=1788\ldots85$ ($2014$ times $8$), we would do the following:

In $\mathbb{Z}_9: [A]=[a_0]+[10][a_1]+\cdots+[10]^n[a_n]=[a_0]+[a_1]+\cdots+[a_n]=[a_0+a_1+\cdots+a_n]$

$[A]=[1+7+2014 \cdot 8+5]=[16125]=[1+6+1+2+5]=[15]=[6] \Rightarrow A \equiv 6 \pmod 9 \Rightarrow A-6=9k \Rightarrow A=9k+6 \Rightarrow \text{ So the remainder of the division of } A \text{ and } 9 \text{ is } 6.$
$$$$
But in this case we a decimal number...What can I do??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems strange to ask for the remainder of a number with a decimal, as you say.  You can do one of two things, depending on how you interpret the question.  You can look for the largest natural number $k$ so that $3k \le 173562014.8976$, then calculate $173562014.8976-3k$ and report the result.  This is the same as ignoring the decimal, finding the normal remainder for natural number division, then adding the decimal back to the remainder.  Otherwise, you can find the $m$ such that $m$ has four decimals and $3m \le 173562014.8976$, then calculate $173562014.8976-3m$.  Your remainder will now be $0.0000, 0.0001,$ or $0.0002$  It corresponds to ignoring the decimal point and treating $173562014.8976$ as $1735620148976$, then putting the decimal point back in.

Comment: Ok!!!Thanks a lot!!!